# 'lidt' instruction not supported in 32-bit mode

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I'm trying to load an idt and once I used the 'lidt' instruction to load the idt it gives me an error:  `error: instruction not supported in 32-bit mode`

code:

```
[bits 32]
[extern _idt]

idt_descriptor:
    dw 4095
    dq _idt

[extern isr1Handler]
isr1:
    call isr1Handler
    iretq
    GLOBAL isr1

load_IDT:
    lidt[idt_descriptor]
    sti
    ret
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: iretq is a 64 bit instruction. Just use iret. In 32-bit iret and iretd are the same thing.

Comment: Oh. You are trying to create 64-bit code. The problem is you have [bits 32]. Did you mean to use [bits 64] ? I didn't notice the tag nor did I notice much else. I'm usually more observent. If 64-bit code it would be iretq but change the bits at the top.

Comment: Rule of thumb: you usually don't need the `bits` directive as the correct operation mode is selected from the object file type.  Double check if it is really needed. and perhaps explain why.